# How to get data value from stdclass object?

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

How to get a data value from stdclass object? If I used `print_r` I get stdclass object..

my expected output is like this:

paper : 21

scissors :22

rock : 12

Actual output :

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [player_item] => 
    [total] => 1 
) 
stdClass Object ( 
    [player_item] => paper 
    [total] => 39 
) 
stdClass Object ( 
    [player_item] => rock 
    [total] => 32 
) 
stdClass Object ( 
    [player_item] => scissors 
    [total] => 12 
)
```

here is my code

Model:

```
       $this->db->select('player_item, COUNT(player_item) as total');
       $this->db->group_by('player_item');
       $query = $this->db->get('rps');
       return $query->result();
```

controller:

```
    $this->load->model('rps_model'); 
    $data3['query']=$this->rps_model->rps_stat();
    $this->load->view('rps_view',$data3);
```

view:

```
foreach($query as $row )
{

    print_r($row);
 }
```

Comment: use $row->player_item. may be it will help you

Comment: `echo "{$row->player_item}: {$row->total} <br/>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view:

```
foreach($query as $row) {
  if(trim($row->player_item) != '') {
    echo $row->player_item . ' : ' . $row->total . '<br/>';
  }
}
```